# Como conseguir el path de un campo tipo file

Tags: javascript

Hola quisiera ayuda con el siguiente problema:
Tengo un formulario con el campo *upload* de tipo file y quisiera **obtener** la *ruta del archivo* que se selecciona y guardarlo en una variable con javascript:

```
 <form action="/upload" enctype="multipar/form-data" method="POST"> 
     <div><input type="file" name="upload"></div>
     <div><input type="submit" "up"></div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Recomiendo que agregues el codigo de lo que has intentado

Comment: <form action="./upload" enctype="multipar/form-data" method="POST"> 
        <div><input type="file" name="upload"></div>
        <div><input type="submit" "up"></div>
        </form>   este es el formulario que estoy usando, lo que me interesa es obtener el path de input tipo file

Comment: Debe [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/98278/edit) su pregunta y alli agregar el codigo

Comment: Gracias @JulianFuentes voy a verlo

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar `jquery` y simplificar muchísimo lo que quieres de este modo:
(Puse una imagen para mostrar que la ruta sirve correctamente pero se puede subir cualquier archivo)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Escuchamos el evento 'change' del input donde cargamos el archivo
  $(document).on('change', 'input[type=file]', function(e) {
    // Obtenemos la ruta temporal mediante el evento
    var TmpPath = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
    // Mostramos la ruta temporal
    $('span').html(TmpPath);
    $('img').attr('src', TmpPath);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="upload"><br /><br />
<span></span><br /><br />
<img width="200" alt="Imagen" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Por motivos de seguridad el navegador no tiene acceso al File System, es decir que no se puede obtener este path normalmente. Buscando en la web dice que solo con Mozila Firefox es posible pero obviamente NO es algo recomendable.

En el siguiente link puedes encontrar mas información y algunas sugerencias: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav